# TypeError: this.state.postsList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm starting learing ReactJs and i am trying to get data from fake api https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 and return title and body post. Unfortunately browser return me error: TypeError: this.state.postsList.map is not a function.

When I am doing the same not for one post but for list with all post titles (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/) everything works fine in code bellow.

```
class Post extends Component {
    state = {
    postsList: {},
  };

componentDidMount() {
  // const postId = this.props.match.params.id
  // fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`)
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
        postsList: data,
    }));

};

renderList = () => this.state.postsList.map((item, id) => <div>>{item.title}></div>);
render() { return (

this.renderList()

  );
}
}
export default Post;
```

Do you know what i have to change? 
I suspect the problem is in mapping as when I am getting all post API return me [] not {} like is this case?

Comment: `postsList: {}` - it's not an array, so it doesn't have a `.map` method.

Comment: You've defined `postList` as an `object` in `state`. `.map()` doesn't work with objects but array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Post extends Component {
    state = {
    postsList: [],
  };

componentDidMount() {
  // const postId = this.props.match.params.id
  // fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`)
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
        postsList: [...data],
    }));

};

renderList = () => this.state.postsList.map((item, id) => <div>>{item.title}></div>);
render() { return (

this.renderList()

  );
}
}
```

`postList` should be an `Array`. You can use the spread operator to force this (but it looks like the index contains an array regardless). I also changed the fetch to retrieve the `/posts` index rather than `/posts/:id`
The key difference here being  that `/posts` returns an Array of `post` objects

Answer (score 1):

Also, initially it is an object and not an array

```
class Post extends Component {
 state = {
    postsList: [] // update here
 };
 componentDidMount() {
  // const postId = this.props.match.params.id
  // fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`)
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
        postsList: Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data], //just to wrap if it is a sinle object
    }));

};

renderList = () => this.state.postsList.map((item, id) => <div>>{item.title}></div>);
render() { return (

this.renderList()

  );
}
}
export default Post;
```

This is the respose you are getting.

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Only arrays have the .map method, here it is returning a single object and you cannot map over it

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here. `PostLists` is declared as an `Object` initially. Declare it as an empty `array`

```
state = { postlists : [] }
```

`render` `return` statement is incorrect, you are returning a function wrapped in a `jsx` separator. Either wrap the inner statement in `Fragments` and `{ }`

```
render(){
    return(
        <>
           { this.renderList() }
        </>
    )
}
```

Or just remove the separator

```
render(){
    return this.renderList()
}
```

If the API call returns an `Object` instead of an array you should leave the declaration as an empty object and map through it's entries

```
renderList = () => Object.keys(this.state.postsList).map((key, id) => <div>>{this.state.postsList[key].title}></div>)
```